# Encoding problem

Tags: java, xml, encoding, sax

I have to parse the content I get from the web and it can contain special characters. In this case the content string appears like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
  <product>
    <id>1</id>
    <price>2.14</price>
    <title>test &#382; test</title>
```

When the contet above is passed to the method characters(), in the class which is extended from org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler:

```
public class ProductsXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {
...

@Override    
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        String elementValue = new String(ch, start, length);
    ...
}
```

I noticed the array `test &#382; test` is broken into three arrays: 'test ', '`&#382;`' and ' test'
so the elementValue is not equal  `test &#382; test` which should be the result. Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Is it necessary to recode the source string:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
  <product>
    <id>1</id>
    <price>2.14</price>
    <title>test &#382; test</title>
```

before it is passed to XML handler class?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As J[on Skeet said in in answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991615/encoding-problem/1991636#1991636), `characters` is called multiple times. What you should do is the following :

- in `startTag`, create a StringBuffer, and note (in a boolean value for example) if you are in the right tag you are searching for.
- in `characters`, if you are in the right tag (if the boolean set earlier is true), put the characters in the StringBuffer
- in `endTag`, if you are getting out of the right tag (see boolean, same thing as earlier), take the content of the StringBuffer and voilà ! Here is your complete string. Don't forget to empty the StringBuffer after that.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that `characters` is being called three times? If so, you just need to make your code handle that - the parser is perfectly at liberty to do this. You shouldn't assume that you'll get all character data in one call.

From the documentation for `DocumentHandler.characters()`:

> SAX parsers may return all contiguous
>   character data in a single chunk, or
>   they may split it into several chunks;
>   however, all of the characters in any
>   single event must come from the same
>   external entity, so that the Locator
>   provides useful information.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do anything about it, this is per the SAX API. Specifically, from http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#characters(char[],%20int,%20int)

> The Parser will call this method to
>   report each chunk of character data.
>   SAX parsers may return all contiguous
>   character data in a single chunk, *or
>   they may split it into several
>   chunks*; however, all of the
>   characters in any single event must
>   come from the same external entity so
>   that the Locator provides useful
>   information.

(My emphasis)